AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle' object has no attribute 'fbind'
I have no idea how to correct this. Ive combed my main and gui files and cant find whats causing it. Any help would be much appreciated.
Ive copied all code exactly as the instructor gave it and Ive checked all indentation but still cant isolate whats causing this error

Please post a [mcve].
